# Android webview custom error page

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am creating application that use WebView to access a online website. I am stuck where I have to add code to check availability of page.

```
public class SpartanWeb extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Adds Progrss bar Support
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Makes Progress bar Visible
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
            Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

    // Get Web view
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings websettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.stopLoading();
    mWebView.clearCache(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // onProgressChanged
    final Activity MyActivity = this;
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            // bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to
            // Loading...
            MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
            MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); // Make the bar
                                                    // disappear after URL
                                                    // is loaded

            // Return the app name after finish loading
            if (progress == 100)
                MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });

}// EOM oc

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

I am trying to add *onReceivedError* but for some reason custom page is not loading.

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) 
{
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
}
```

Please advise what to do.

Comment: implement your onRecievedError in setWEbChromeClient

Comment: if i put onReceiveError like this `mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) 
   {
   mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
   }` still receiving default error - webpage not available

Comment: I added to setWebViewClient and its working :) `mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
   @Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
          mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/greska.html");
   } });`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can call loadErrorPage(view) function in the `onReceivedError` function.

The following code will load the error content you need to show.Here i am load the html file with `loadDataWithBaseURL`.

```
public void loadErrorPage(WebView webview){
        if(webview!=null){

            String htmlData ="<html><body><div align=\"center\" >"This is the description for the load fail : "+description+"\nThe failed url is : "+failingUrl+"\n"</div></body>";

            webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
            webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
            webview.invalidate();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Before that, i need help how to implement onReceivedError

Comment: add this code ---->mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.i("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode);
          loadErrorPage(view);
    }
 });         ========   This may help you.

Comment: thanks for help, i added my code to mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() and it is working now

Comment: Is there a way to handle url that is blocked or not safe? How to catch those type of url? Because I don't think the onReceivedError can catch the url that is blocked/not safe since these url are technically not error, but they are just not safe. Is there a method to catch these blocked/not safe url? Thank you

Comment: It's working fine but if the user go to destination page after connecting to internet, and on back press this error page is displaying. How to remove this from error page in backward history..?

Answer (score 11):

I added `onReceivedError` to `mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient` so now it's working. Thanks for tips.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
        @Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
               mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
        } });
```

Answer (score -6):

You can use the following code ..

```
public class TestResultWebclient extends WebViewClient {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TermsAndCondsMrupeeActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialog != null)
                try {

                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }

                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no code relating to showing the error message!