# Load local html if the url page is not loaded (Android Studio)

Tags: android, html, url, webview, android-webview

I am trying to load the URL to webView on Android Studio. I load the URL based on user input (in my code below is urlResult). Sometimes the user can input in the form of "https://exampleweb.com", or "https://www.exampleweb.com", or "www.exampleweb.com", or "exampleweb.com". Sometimes, the URL that is entered by the user may not load anything (either the link is not active, blocked, does not exist, etc.). When this happens, I would like to show an error HTML page that I already created locally (errorpage.html). How can I achieve this? Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
public class WebResult extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_result);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView_UrlResult);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/errorpage.html");
            }
        });


        if (urlResult.startsWith("https://")) {
            webView.loadUrl(urlResult);

        } else {
            webView.loadUrl("https://" + urlResult);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284186/android-webview-custom-error-page

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to handle url that is blocked or not safe? How to catch those type of url? Because I don't think the onReceivedError can catch the url that is blocked/not safe since these url are technically not error, but they are just not safe. Is there a method to catch these blocked/not safe url? Thank you